# Wamp server 2.5 wrong page redirection

Tags: url, redirect, wamp

I installed wamp server 2.5 with PHP 5.5. Now, when i try to access my project pages from the front page(wamp home page), it redirect to a wrong url and shows google cannot find this page.

The problem definition is

I enter to wamp using `http://localhost`

There I have many project. Suppose I click on `sample_project`

Then the page redirects to `sample_projects/`

And Google Chrome displays the error `chrome cannot find this webpage`

There are two fields are swown red marks in my wamp PHP extensions area. They are `php_enchant` and `php_opcache`

What is the problem with my wamp??am I missing something? Help please

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Honestly I think its highly inefficient to create Virtual Host for every.. single.. project. So after investigating I found a key variable in:

```
wamp/www/index.php.
```

After quick analysis, the variable's obvious purpose is to remove the 'localhost' in projects links.

Change this line:

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

To this:

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

Comment: How is it inefficient. It takes 2 mins for each project after you have the first one setup.

Comment: that's incredibly stupid I had to do that, but I'm glad you figured this out. I was about to go hard code the link haha. thanks man

Comment: With every next wamp version new idiotic tricks. Why they do that to us? Thanks for the great answer (:

Comment: https://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Comment: The reason why `VirtualHost` exists is to have multiple _projects_ on one host, its only inefficient if you don't know how to use it ..

Answer (score 9):

**WAMPServer 2.5 Homepage the Your Projects Menu and Virtual Hosts**

There has been a change of concept in WampServer 2.5 and there is a good reason for this change!

In WampServer 2.5 it is now STRONGLY encouraged to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects, even if you hold then in a `\wamp\www\subfolder` structure.

[Virtual Hosts Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/)

[Virtual Host Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

The WampServer home page ( \wamp\www\index.php ) now expects you to have created a Virtual Host for all your projects and will therefore work properly only if you do so.

**History**

In order to make life easier for beginners using WampServer to learn PHP Apache and MySQL it was suggested that you create subfolders under the `\wamp\www\` folder.

```
wamp
  |-- www
       |-- Chapter1
       |-- Chapter2
       |-- etc
```

These subfolders would then show as links in the WampServer Homepage under a menu called 'Your Projects' and these links would contain a link to `localhost/subfoldername`.

**Acceptable only for simple tutorials**

This made life easy for the complete beginner, and was perfectly acceptable for example for those following tutorials to learn PHP coding.
However it was never intended for use when developing a real web site that you would later want to copy to your live hosted server.
In fact if you did use this mechanism it often caused problems as the live sites configuration would not match your development configuration.

**The Problem** for real website development.

The reason for this is of course that the default DocumentRoot setting for wamp is

`DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"`

regardless of what your subfolder was called.
This ment that often used PHP code that queried the structure or your site received different information when running on your development WampServer to what it would receive when running on a live hosted server, where the DocumentRoot configuration points to the folder at the top of the website file hierarchy.
This kind of code exists in many frameworks and CMS's for example WordPress and Joomla etc.

**For Example**

Lets say we have a project called project1 held in `wamp\www\project1` and run incorrectly as `localhost/project1/index.php`

This is what would be reported by some of the PHP command in question:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = localhost
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = localhost
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = c:/wamp/www
```

Now if we had correctly defined that site using a Virtual Host definition and ran it as `http://project1` the results on the WAMPServer devlopment site will match those received when on a live hosted environment.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = project1
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = project1
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = c:/wamp/www/project1
```

Now this difference may seem trivial at first but if you were to use a framework like WordPress or one of the CMS's like Joomla for example, this can and does cause problems when you move your site to a live server.

### How to create a Virtual Host in WampServer

Actually this should work basically the same for any wndows Apache server, with differences only in where you may find the Apache config files.

There are 3 steps to create your first Virtual Host in Apache, and only 2 if you already have one defined.

1. Create the Virtual Host definition(s)
2. Add your new domain name to the HOSTS file.
3. Uncomment the line in httpd.conf that includes the Virtual Hosts definition file.

**Step 1**, Create the Virtual Host definition(s)

Edit the file called `httpd-hosts.conf` which for WampServer lives in

```
\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-hosts.conf
```

*(Apache version numbers may differ, engage brain before continuing)*

*If this is the first time you edit this file, remove the default example code, it is of no use.*

I am assuming we want to create a definition for a site called project1 that lives in

```
\wamp\www\project1
```

Very important, first we must make sure that localhost still works so that is the first VHOST definition we will put in this file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now we define our project: and this of course you do for each of your projects as you start a new one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/project1"
    ServerName project1
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/project1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

NOTE: That each Virtual Host as its own `DocumentRoot` defined. There are also many other parameters you can add to a Virtual Hosts definition, check the Apache documentation.

***Small aside***

The way virtual hosts work in Apache: The first definition in this file will also be the default site, so should the domain name used in the browser not match any actually defined virtually hosted domain, making localhost the first domain in the file will therefore make it the site that is loaded if a hack attempt just uses your IP Address.
So if we ensure that the Apache security for this domain **is ALWAYS SET TO**

```
Require local
```

any casual hack from an external address will receive an error and not get into your PC, but should you misspell a domain you will be shown the WampServer homepage, because you are on the same PC as WampServer and therfore `local`.

**Setp 2**:

Add your new domain name to the HOSTS file.
Now we need to add the domain name that we have used in the Virtual Host definition to the HOSTS file so that windows knows where to find it. This is similiar to creating a DNS A record, but it is only visible in this case on this specific PC.

Edit `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

The file has no extension and should remain that way. Watch out for notepad, as it may try and add a `.txt` extension if you have no better editor.
I suggest you download Notepad++, its free and a very good editor.

Also this is a protected file so you must edit it with administrator privileges, so launch you editor using the [Run as Administrator](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html) menu option.

The hosts file should look like this when you have completed these edits

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 project1

::1 localhost
::1 project1
```

Note that you should have definitions in here for the IPV4 loopback address `127.0.0.1` and also the IPV6 loopback address `::1` as Apache is now IPV6 aware and the browser will use either IPV4 or IPV6 or both. I have no idea how it decides which to use, but it can use either if you have the IPV6 stack turned on, and most window OS's do as of XP SP3.

Now we must tell windows to refresh its domain name cache, so launch a command window again using the [Run as Administrator](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html) menu option again, and do the following.

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

This forces windows to clear its domain name cache and reload it, in reloading it will re-read the HOSTS file so now it knows about the domain `project1`.

**Step 3**: Uncomment the line in httpd.conf that includes the Virtual Hosts definition file.

Edit your httpd.conf, use the wampmanager.exe menus to make sure you edit the correct file.

Find this line in httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And just remove the `#` to uncomment that line.

To activate this change in you running Apache we must now stop and restart the Apache service.

```
wampmanager.exe -> Apache -> Service -> Restart Service
```

Now if the WAMP icon in the system tray does not go GREEN again, it means you have probably done something wrong in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-hosts.conf` file.

If so here is a useful mechanism to find out what is wrong. It uses a feature of the Apache exe (httpd.exe) to check its config files and report errors by filename and line numbers.

Launch a command window.

```
cd \wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin
httpd -t
```

So fix the errors and retest again until you get the output

```
Syntax OK
```

***Now there is one more thing.***

There are actually 2 new menu items on the wampmanager menu system. One called [b]'My Projects'[/b] which is turned on by default.
And a second one, called [b]'My Virtual Hosts'[/b], which is not activated by default.

'My Projects' will list any sub directory of the \wamp\www directory and provide a link to launch the site in that sub directory.
As I said earlier, it launches 'project1` and not 'localhost/project1' so to make the link work we must create a Virtual Host definition to make this link actually launch that site in your browser, without the Virtual Host definition it's likely to launch a web search for the site name as a keyword or just return a site not found condition.

The 'My Virtual Hosts' menu item is a little different. It searches the file that is used to define Virtual Hosts ( we will get to that in a minute ) and creates menu links for each ServerName parameter it finds and creates a menu item for each one.
This may seem a little confusing as once we create a Virtual Host definition for the sub directories of the \wamp\www folder some items will appear on both of the 'My Projects' menu and the 'My Virtual Hosts' menu's.

**How do I turn this other 'My Virtual Hosts' menu on?**

- Make a backup of the \wamp\wampmanager.tpl file, just in case you make a mistake, its a very important file.
- Edit the \wamp\wampmanager.tpl
- Find this parameter `;WAMPPROJECTSUBMENU`, its in the '[Menu.Left]' section.
- Add this new parameter `;WAMPVHOSTSUBMENU` either before or after the `;WAMPPROJECTSUBMENU` parameter.
- Save the file.
- Now right click the wampmanager icon, and select 'Refresh'. If this does not add the menu, 'exit' and restart wampmanager.

**Big Note**
The new menu will only appear if you already have some Virtual Hosts defined! Otherwise you will see no difference until you define a VHOST.

Comment: I think this works. But when I do, after change all the things as above, the wamp appears green. But localhost says "you don't have the permission to access this site".. why so?

Comment: Are you getting this error when browsing on the same PC that is runnng WAMPServer?

Comment: Yeah.. On the same pc in which I installed my WAMP server

Comment: What does your apache error log and apache access log tell you?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that Wampserver now expects everyone to create a virtual host for every project under development offline on their laptops? 
Your instructions seem to be very good but probably much too complicated for beginners (also, I suspect that the file path in your instructions for step2: adding the new domain to the HOSTS file only applies to 32-bit Windows)?

The solution from Rogue above (change $suppress_localhost="true"; to $suppress_localhost="false"; in c:/wamp/www/index.php) will work perfectly for 99% of the users who develop more than one website on their laptops.

Also uploading a completed website to an online server should not cause any real problems.
BUt perhaps Wampserver had another reason for adding the $suppress_localhost code?

Comment: The solution above is the correct one and the HOSTS file applies to 64-bit Windows as well, not just 32-bit. Just try it.