# URL generated in Wamp is missing the local host prefix

Tags: php, apache, wamp

when pressing a site link from wamp localhost dashboard, site does not include the localhost prefix, therefore not working.

per example.

pressing:my site
results in address: mysite
and i have to manualy put the localhost prefix in order for the site to load:
localhost/mysite

how can i fix this?

appreciate any help.
thanks
Jonathan

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: its not code, it just the localhost dashboard site links in Wamp

Comment: I answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909645/wamp-server-2-5-wrong-page-redirection/23917142#23917142

Comment: thanks a lot. it seems too much to add manualy a virtual host to each site.. i have 100's.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to create virtual host if u don't need. Just do the following

open `www/wamp/index.php`

then change the line

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

to

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

This works good for me

Comment: with pleasure.Please accept the answer if it is usefull.:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use html base tag to specify host for all links. More details here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: i do not want to change it per site, i want to correct the WAMP settings.