# Vhost can't find server

Tags: apache, wampserver, vhosts

I am following RiggsFolly answer, on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909645/wamp-server-2-5-wrong-page-redirection) question and [these](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) examples and so far everything went well, but when I click on the vhost FF says that it can't find the server. How can this fixed?
I am using Wampserver 2.5.

I get this in the adress bar : `http://www.cakeprebuild.com/`

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /wamp/www/CakePreBuild
    ServerName www.CakePreBuild.com
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/CakePreBuild">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost

127.0.0.1 CakePreBuild

::1 localhost
::1 CakePreBuild
```

Comment: Tell us where the link you are clicking tries to take you - what does the address bar in FF say?

Comment: @SarahKemp Which link? I am accessing the vhost through wampservermenu->My Virtual Hosts->www.CakePreBuild.com

Comment: And what did you put in your hosts file?

Comment: Add your httpd-vhosts.conf file to your question so we can review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes

Your VHOSTS Definition

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/CakePreBuild"
    ServerName cakeprebuild.com
    ServerAlias www.cakeprebuild.com
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/CakePreBuild">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Your HOSTS file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 cakeprebuild.com

::1 localhost
::1 cakeprebuild.com
```

Personally I would avoid using the `.com` tld for sites your are developing and use something like `.dev`.
If a site actually existed called `cakeprebuild.com` having added that name to the HOSTS file would mean you would never be able to access the actual live site from this PC as you have redirected it to this PC.

Comment: Awsesome, it worked perfectly. I also took your advice, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing wamp is not configured correctly for your vhost.  FF (and chrome to a lesser degree) will try and help you out add the

`'http://www.' and '.com'`

around what you entered, if what you entered didn't return a result.  Turn off wamp and type in 'localhost', you'll be redirected to

`http://www.localhost.com`

Comment: I can access to localhost with no issues but to CakePreBuild vhost I can't.

Comment: I was saying turn off wamp, and then try localhost.  You will get redirected to: http://www.localhost.com

Comment: Ok sorry, I get the same result, both vhosts can't find the server. Want me to post httpd-vhosts.conf?